# Access Microsoft Live services from Python application

Tags: python, live, onedrive

I need to access microsoft skydrive from my python app. Is there a SOAP or REST service that Microsoft provides for developers?

If there is no web service, does any python library that allows to access skydrive exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[No](http://www.windowslivetaskforce.com/view/99) on the official API.

There are a couple of .NET libraries for unofficial access, which you could use from IronPython.

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API for SkyDrive now.

Broadly the protocol is as follows:

- [Get a client ID for your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx#clientid).
- Use the client ID to [get the user signed in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx#code-snippet-19), thus obtaining an access token.
- Use the access token to [get info about the current user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx#code-snippet-26) because at first the only relevant thing you know about the current user is the name "me".
- Use the access token and user ID to operate the [SkyDrive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx). For example you'll probably want to [get the user's top-level folder in the SkyDrive directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#rcode-snippet-5).

There are also some Python modules available, such as [python-skydrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-skydrive) and [txSkyDrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txSkyDrive). But those are only for Python 2.7.